# PHP Preg Match, get value between specific pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a php application that saves the following output on database:

```
::cck_gx::gx::/cck_gx::
::i1|0|gx::Lorem::/i1|0|gx::
::head1|0|gx::ipsum::/head1|0|gx::
::tx1|0|gx::dolor, fithos lusec.::/tx1|0|gx::
::cckend_gx::::/cckend_gx::
::cck_gx::gx::/cck_gx::
::i1|1|gx::calendar::/i1|1|gx::
::head1|1|gx::1 Fatura Grátis Por Ano::/head1|1|gx::
::tx1|1|gx::10% de cada mensalidade é reservado, e o valor acumulado até a renovação do Seguro Porto Seguro ou Azul Seguros, é devolvido em forma de desconto. Ou seja, Cliente Conecta pode ter uma fatura de celular grátis por ano.::/tx1|1|gx::
```

And I want to retrieve information from this output using preg_match. For example retrieving any value in the same place of "Lorem" and "ipsum" on the example below:

```
::i1|0|gx::Lorem::/i1|0|gx::
::head1|0|gx::ipsum::/head1|0|gx::
```

But I am clueless with preg_match syntax.

I understand that I will need a different preg match for each "label" (like a preg_match to retrieve all "i1" values, a different preg_match to retrieve all "head1" and so on). I just need one example that works to understand the correct pattern.

Also, in the last line is a example with a lot of different characters like numbers, commas, "%" and others, I am not sure if this will mess with syntax.

Here two of my failed attempts:

```
preg_match('~[::i1|0|gx::](.*?)[/::i1|0|gx::]~', $maindata->introtext, $match1a);
 preg_match('::i1|0|gx::(.*?)::/i1|0|gx::', $maindata->introtext, $match1a);
 preg_match('/::i1|0|gx::(.*?)::.i1|0|gx::/', $maindata->introtext, $match1a);
```

Comment: `|`s need to be escaped. I think `[:` is being read as a POSIX character class. Are you trying to do groupings with those as well? Try running your regexs on a site like regex101.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help

```
<?php
    $str = '::i1|0|gx::Lorem::/i1|0|gx::';
    preg_match('/(?<=gx::).*(?=::\/)/', $str);
```

You can also use `preg_match_all()`

```
<?php
    $str = '::cck_gx::gx::/cck_gx::
    ::i1|0|gx::Lorem::/i1|0|gx::
    ::head1|0|gx::ipsum::/head1|0|gx::
    ::tx1|0|gx::dolor, fithos lusec.::/tx1|0|gx::
    ::cckend_gx::::/cckend_gx::
    ::cck_gx::gx::/cck_gx::
    ::i1|1|gx::calendar::/i1|1|gx::
    ::head1|1|gx::1 Fatura Grátis Por Ano::/head1|1|gx::';

    preg_match_all('/(?<=gx::).*(?=::\/)/', $str, $matches);
    var_dump($matches);
```

`(?<=gx::)` Positive Lookbehind - Assert that the regex below can be matched

`.` matches any character (except newline)

`*` Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible

`(?=::\/)` Positive Lookahead - Assert that the regex below can be matched

`::` matches the characters :: literally

`\/` matches the character / literally

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot;

Answer (score 0):

You could come up with the following regex:

```
::(\w+)[^::]+::(?<content>.*?)::(?=\/\1)
```

A PHP code snippet and the explanation of the regex in freespacing mode is shown below. See an [example for it on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/fO7wN8/1).

```
<?php
$string = '
::cck_gx::gx::/cck_gx::
::i1|0|gx::Lorem::/i1|0|gx::
::head1|0|gx::ipsum::/head1|0|gx::
::tx1|0|gx::dolor, fithos lusec.::/tx1|0|gx::
::cckend_gx::::/cckend_gx::
::cck_gx::gx::/cck_gx::
::i1|1|gx::calendar::/i1|1|gx::
::head1|1|gx::1 Fatura Grátis Por Ano::/head1|1|gx::
';

$regex = '~
        ::
        (\w+)
        # tag 
        [^:]+::
        # match everything except a colon, then two colons 
        (?<content>.*?)
        # match everything lazily and capture it in a group called content
        ::
        # two colons 
        (?=\/\1)
        # closing tag with tag captured in group 1
        ~x';
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches["content"]);
/* output:
Array
(
    [0] => gx
    [1] => Lorem
    [2] => ipsum
    [3] => dolor, fithos lusec.
    [4] => 
    [5] => gx
    [6] => calendar
    [7] => 1 Fatura Grátis Por Ano
)
*/
?>
```